# Python: Why is popping off a queue faster than for-in block?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, while-loop

I have been working on a python script to analyze CSVs.  Some of these files are fairly large (1-2 million records), and the script was taking hours to complete.

I changed the way the records are processed from a `for-in` loop to a `while` loop, and the speedup was remarkable.  Demonstration below:

```
>>> def for_list():
...     for d in data:
...             bunk = d**d
... 
>>> def while_list():
...     while data:
...             d = data.pop(0)
...             bunk = d**d
... 
>>> data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit(for_list)
1.0698931217193604
>>> timeit.timeit(while_list)
0.14515399932861328
```

Almost an order of magnitude faster.  I've never looked at python bytecode, but I though it might be telling, but it turns out `while_list` has more instructions.

So what's going on here?  Is there a principle here I can apply to other programs?  Are there scenarios where the `for` would be ten times faster than the `while`?

**EDIT:** As @HappyLeapSecond pointed out, I didn't quite understand exactly what was going on inside `timeit`  The discrepancy is gone with the following:

```
>>> def for_list():
...     data = [x for x in range(1000)]
...     for d in data:
...             bunk = d**d
... 
>>> def while_list():
...     data = [x for x in range(1000)]
...     while data:
...             d = data.pop(0)
...             bunk = d**d
>>> timeit.timeit(while_list, number=1000)
12.006330966949463
>>> timeit.timeit(for_list, number=1000)
11.847280025482178
```

Which makes it very odd that my "real" script sped up so much with such a simple change.  My best guess is that the iteration method is requiring more swapping?  I have a 40G swap partition, the script fills about 15-20G of it.  Would popping reduce swapping?

Comment: I can imagine that creating an iterator for a `for` loop may be relatively costly. Try to make your list way longer, e.g. 100k entries, and compare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`while_list` is mutating the global `data`. `timeit.timeit` does not reset the value of `data`. `timeit.timeit` calls `for_list` and  `while_list` a million times each by default. After the first call to `while_list`, subsequent calls to `while_list` return after performing 0 loops because `data` is already empty.

You need to reset the value of `data` before each call to `for_list` and `while_list` to perform a fair benchmark.

---

```
import timeit

def for_list(data):
    for d in data:
        bunk = d ** d


def while_list(data):
    while data:
        d = data.pop(0)
        bunk = d ** d

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

print(timeit.timeit('data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; for_list(data)', 'from __main__ import for_list'))
# 0.959696054459

print(timeit.timeit('data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; while_list(data)', 'from __main__ import while_list'))
# 2.40107011795
```

`pop(0)` is a `O(n)` operation. Performing that inside a loop of length `n` makes `while_list` have an overall time complexity `O(n**2)`, compared to `O(n)` complexity for `for_list`. So as expected, `for_list` is faster, and the advantage grows as `n`, the length of `data`, gets larger.

Comment: The above example runs `for_list` first - so your argument is not really applicable imho.

Comment: @sebastian: `timeit.timeit` repeat the call to `while_list` a million times by default. After the first call to `while_list`, `data` is empty. So for 999,999 runs, `while_loop` completes too soon.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: How are  you resetting `data`? It has to be done in the statement, not the setup because the setup is only run once.